# Make sure that random() does not return 0?

Tags: objective-c, random

I'm looking at the documentation for random():

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/srandomdev.3.html#//apple_ref/c/func/random

It returns successive pseudo-random numbers in the range from 0 to (2**31)-1.

I don't want it to return 0 ever.

I'm thinking about writing:

```
long rand = random() + 1;
```

But if I'm not mistaken, long can be 32-bits on a 32-bit processor. I guess I would risk stack overflow then.

What is the best approach to getting a random number between 1 and (2**31)-1?

Comment: The obvious answer is to use `arc4random_uniform` instead which allows you to specify the upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long rand = 0;
while (rand == 0) {
    rand = random();
}
```

This will almost absolutely certainly run exactly once. In a very, very rare case (that will never happen), it will run twice.

(Note that this is just a simplified version of how `arc4random_uniform` works. If you can use that function, as suggested by Jeff, you should.)

Comment: theoretically it can happen infinite times.

Comment: Not true. Your CPU will decay into fundamental particles in finite, and highly predicable time. There are no infinite loops on real computers. Neither this observation, nor the previous one, are particularly helpful in designing real systems, however. This loop will not run more than twice unless `random()` is broken. Observed counter-examples welcome.

Comment: Just for calculation purposes, the odds of encountering 0 twice in a row on a 32-bit machine is 1:1.8e19. At a billion numbers per second, you'd expect two in a row to happen once every 500 years or so. Three times in a row is almost 1:8e28. We expect the heat death of the universe before that happened. If you encounter these kinds of incredibly unlikely events, the certain answer is that `random()` is broken.

Comment: thanks Napier, anyway I said "theoretically", your family name sounds like a planet name though.

Answer (score 5):

`NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(N) + 1;`

This will generate a number between 1 and N. `arc4random_uniform(N)` generates a number between 0 and N-1.

You should have no problem with overflow.

Comment: Is the same true when using random()?

Comment: I need to use random(). I think that method can lead to overflow: "An integral type with n bits can encode 2^n numbers; for example an unsigned type typically represents the non-negative values 0 through 2^(n−1). ". The maximum number + will overflow if I understand correctly.

Comment: Why do you need to use random()?

Comment: I agree that this a better answer than mine if you can use that function (which you should). My answer is just a simplified implementation of `arc4random_uniform` which also uses a loop to make sure you're in the right range.

Comment: @Jeff: I need to use a seeded randomizer

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value returned by `random()` is `RAND_MAX`, so you can do this:

```
long rand = 1 + (random() % RAND_MAX);
```

When `random()` returns a value between zero and `RAND_MAX-1`, inclusive, you offset it by adding `1`. When `random()` returns exactly `RAND_MAX`, modulo operator `%` converts the result to zero, so `rand` would be `1` again.

The drawback of this approach is that the probability of getting `1` becomes roughly twice as high as that of getting any other number.

Comment: And that will overflow if RAND_MAX is large enough.

Comment: @gnasher729 The range of `x % RAND_MAX` is zero to `RAND_MAX-1`, inclusive, so adding `1` is safe as long as `RAND_MAX` itself does not overflow.

Comment: Introducing modulo bias, even incredibly small bias, is a very bad habit for anyone to pick up. Looping is almost certainly faster in all real cases (testing against 0 is one instruction, vs performing a modulo and an addition). There's no reason to introduce the bias IMO, and developers should have the habit drummed out of them (because in other systems it really can matter).

Comment: @RobNapier I agree, modulo bias is very bad - hence the reason to avoid `random()` when something less than its full range is desired. That's why I'd go for `arc4random_uniform` in production code. Since OP wants to use `random`, a one-liner would probably get the job done.